# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException object reference not set... ASP.net AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Is anyone able to understand why m I getting this error?

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

SOURCE: ScriptResource.axd

So here is the thing...

I have a button when first clicked (after first site access) works, but after that I always get the error. I tried to debug the subject by putting a debug point at the first line in Page_Load event but its not even getting there.

The error is showing before that on that ScriptResources.axd file which is made of javascript so i tried to debug it but i don't really understand what is going on so i couldn't find the problem.

From what i can understand, somehow, when i first click the button, i must not being initialize some controll i should, but i just can't figure it out.

button id = btnFiltra

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(onPageLoad);
    </script>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pHeader" CssClass="PVHeaderBackground">
        <img alt="Planview" src="Images/logo_planview.png" class="PVLogoBackImgleft"/>
        <div id="PTLogo" class="PTLogosRight">
            <img src="Images/logo_meo_preto.png" alt="Meo" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto"/>
            <img src="Images/Ptlogo.jpg" alt="PT" style="height:50px; width:auto; margin-left:10px; vertical-align:middle;margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto"/>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upBody" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pOpcoesGlobais" >
            <asp:Button ID="btnExtrair" runat="server" OnClientClick="umProjetoApenas()" OnClick="btnExtrair_OnClick" Text="Extrair Dados"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAtualizar" runat="server" OnClientClick="umProjetoApenas()" OnClick="btnAtualizar_OnClick" Text="Atualizar Dados"/>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pTarefaOkFaturar" Visible="true" style="display:none;" Width="100%" Height="100%" >
            <div style="width:100%; height:10%">
                <b>Ao confirmar que a tarefa pode ser faturada, todas as parcelas sem documento passarão a ser faturadas de forma automática.</b>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCheckParcelas" CssClass="PVPortlet"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%;position: absolute;bottom: 10px;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnOkFaturarCancelar" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" OnClick="btnOkFaturarCancelar_OnClick" style="float:left;margin-left: 10px;"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnOkFaturarOk" runat="server" Text="Concordo" OnClick="btnOkFaturarOk_OnClick" style="float:right;margin-right: 10px;" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pBody">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upFiltros" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lCliente" runat="server" Text="Cliente"/>               
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbCliente" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="txbCliente_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="txbCliente" 
                        PopupControlID="pPopUpCliente" Position="Bottom" >
                    </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pPopUpCliente" runat="server" Height="116px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight" ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Style="display: none" >
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCliente" runat="server" DataTextField="DESCRICAO" onChange="uncheckOnTodos(this)" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="False" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Todos" Value="all" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lPedido" runat="server" Text="Pedido"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbPedido" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="txbPedido_PopupControlExtender" runat="server"
                        Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="txbPedido" 
                        PopupControlID="pPopUpPedido" Position="Bottom" >
                    </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pPopUpPedido" runat="server" Height="116px" 
                         BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight"
                         ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Style="display: none" >
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPedido" runat="server" 
                             DataTextField="DESCRICAO" onChange="uncheckOnTodos(this)"
                             DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="False" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Todos" Value="all" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lProjeto" runat="server" Text="Projeto"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbProjeto" runat="server"/>

                    <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="txbProjeto_PopupControlExtender" runat="server"
                        Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="txbProjeto" 
                        PopupControlID="pPopUpProjeto" Position="Bottom" >
                    </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pPopUpProjeto" runat="server" Height="116px" 
                         BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight" ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Style="display: none" >
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblProjeto" runat="server" 
                             DataTextField="DESCRICAO" onChange="uncheckOnTodos(this)"
                             DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="False" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Todos" Value="all" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFiltra" Text="Pesquisar" 
                        onclick="btnFiltra_Click"/>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprgTarefas" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upTarefas" DisplayAfter="2000" >
                <ProgressTemplate>Loading...</ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTarefas" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFiltra" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAtualizar" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExtrair" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="dTabelaTarefaHeader" class="PVPortletHeader">
                        <div id="dTabelaTarefasOpcoes" class="PVPortletHeaderOpcoes"></div>
                        <b>Tarefas Faturação</b>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pgvTarefasEmpty" Visible="false">
                        <table class="PVPortlet">
                             <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Projeto</th>
                                    <th>Tarefa</th>
                                    <th>Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Pedido</th>
                                    <th>Inicio</th>
                                    <th>Fim</th>
                                    <th>Faturar?</th>
                                    <th>Planeado</th>
                                    <th>Remanescente</th>
                                    <th>Faturado</th>
                                    <th>Entidade</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="13">Sem dados...</td>
                                </tr>
                             </tbody>                   
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvTarefas" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="PVPortlet" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="PVPortletSelectedRow"
                        onselectedindexchanged="gvTarefas_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="ID"
                        OnRowCreated="gvTarefas_OnRowCreated">
                        <columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Projeto" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Projeto" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tarefa" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Tarefa" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cliente" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Cliente" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pedido" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Pedido" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataInicio" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" HeaderText="Inicio" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataFim" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" HeaderText="Fim" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Faturar?">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbFaturar" Checked='<%# Eval("ProntoAFaturar") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cb_OnCheckedChanged"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Planeado" HeaderText="Planeado" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Remanescente" HeaderText="Remanescente" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Faturado" HeaderText="Faturado" />
                            <utl:CompositeBoundField HeaderText="Entidade" DataField="EntidadeResponsavel.Descricao" />
                        </columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprgParcelas" runat="server" 
                AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upParcelas" DisplayAfter="2000">
                <ProgressTemplate>Loading...</ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upParcelas" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="gvTarefas" 
                        EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="gvParcelas" EventName="RowEditing" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div ID="dTabelaParcelasHeader" class="PVPortletHeader">
                        <b>Parcelas Faturação</b>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pgvParcelasEmpty" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <table class="PVPortlet">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Auto</th>
                                    <th>DataEnvio</th>
                                    <th>Descrição</th>
                                    <th>Valor</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="6">Sem dados...</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvParcelas" runat="server"   AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"  AutoGenerateEditButton="true"AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"  CssClass="PVPortlet" DataKeyNames="ID"  OnRowCancelingEdit="gvParcelas_OnRowCancelingEdit" 
OnRowCommand="gvParcelas_OnRowCommand"  OnRowCreated="gvParcelas_OnRowCreated" OnRowDeleting="gvParcelas_OnRowDeleting"  OnRowEditing="gvParcelas_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvParcelas_OnRowUpdating"  Visible="false" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="PVPortletSelectedRow"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="obterDocumento_OnSeacrh" ShowFooter="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lIDParcela" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lIDParcela" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnParcelaNovo" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Novo" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Auto">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAuto" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Auto") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAuto" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Auto") %>' Enabled="false"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAuto" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DataEnvio">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbDataEnvio" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DataEnvio","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' />
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txbDataEnvio_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                        DefaultView="Months" Enabled="True" Format="MM-yyyy" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" 
                                        TargetControlID="txbDataEnvio">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lDataEnvio" runat="server" 
                                        Text='<%# Eval("DataEnvio","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbDataEnvio" runat="server" Text="" />
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txbDataEnvio_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                        DefaultView="Months" Enabled="True" Format="MM-yyyy" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" 
                                        TargetControlID="txbDataEnvio">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descrição">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbDescricao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descricao") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lDescricao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descricao") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbDescricao" runat="server" Text="" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valor">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbValor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Valor") %>' />
                                    <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txbValor_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server" FilterType="Custom" TargetControlID="txbValor" ValidChars="0123456789,">
                                    </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lValor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Valor") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbValor" runat="server" Text="" />
                                    <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txbValor_FilteredTextBoxExtender" 
                                        runat="server" FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txbValor">
                                    </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprgDocumentos" runat="server" 
                AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upDocumentos" DisplayAfter="2000">
                <ProgressTemplate>Loading...</ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDocumentos" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div ID="dTabelaDocumentosHeader" class="PVPortletHeader">
                        <div ID="dTabelaDocumentosOpcoes" class="PVPortletHeaderOpcoes">
                            <asp:Label ID="lDocInicio" runat="server" Text="Inicio" style="float:left;"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txbInicio" runat="server" style="float:left;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txbInicio_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txbInicio">
                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:Label ID="lDocFim" runat="server" Text="Fim" style="float:left;"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txbFim" runat="server" style="float:left;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txbFim_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txbFim">
                            </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDocFiltro" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" style="float:left;" OnClick="obterDocumento_OnSeacrh"/>
                        </div>
                        <b>Documentos Faturação</b>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNovoDocumento" runat="server" OnClientClick="abrirDocumento(0);" Text="Novo" style="float:right;"/>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pgvDocumentosEmpty" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <table class="PVPortlet">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Fatura</th>
                                    <th>Enviado</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Tipo</th>
                                    <th>Descrição</th>
                                    <th>Valor</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="8">Sem dados...</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDocumentos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="false" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" CssClass="PVPortlet">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Abrir" runat="server" ID="lbtnAbrirDoc" OnClientClick='<%#"abrirDocumento(" + Eval("ID") + ");"%>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" HtmlEncode="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NFATURA" HeaderText="Fatura" HtmlEncode="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EnviadoA" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" HeaderText="Enviado" HtmlEncode="false" />
                            <utl:CompositeBoundField DataField="Estado.Descricao" HeaderText="Estado" HtmlEncode="false" />
                            <utl:CompositeBoundField DataField="Tipo.Descricao" HeaderText="Tipo" HtmlEncode="false" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descrição">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lCabecalho" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Cabecalho").ToString().Cut(30,true)+"-"+Eval("Periodo")%>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Valor" HeaderText="Valor" HtmlEncode="false" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>    
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server SIde

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToUpper();
                sessionID = Session.SessionID;

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    Session["USER_" + sessionID] = userName;
                    Session["TAREFAS_INV_" + sessionID] = null;
                    Session["PARCELAS_"+sessionID] = null;
                    Session["DOCUMENTOS_"+sessionID] = null;

                    carregaDadosFiltros();

                    string idPrj = null;
                    obtemParametrosEntrada(ref idPrj);

                    pgvDocumentosEmpty.Visible = true;
                    pgvParcelasEmpty.Visible = true;
                    pgvTarefasEmpty.Visible = true;
                    gvDocumentos.Visible = false;
                    gvParcelas.Visible = false;
                    gvTarefas.Visible = false;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idPrj))
                    {
                        bool filtra = true;
                        if (cblProjeto.Items.FindByValue(idPrj) != null)
                        {
                            cblProjeto.SelectedValue = idPrj;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string nome = InvDataAccess.obterNomeProjeto(idPrj);
                            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
                            {
                                ListItem prj = new ListItem(nome, idPrj, true);
                                cblProjeto.Items.Add(prj);
                                cblProjeto.SelectedValue = prj.Value;
                            }
                            else
                                filtra = false;
                        }
                        cblCliente.SelectedValue = "all";
                        cblPedido.SelectedValue = "all";
                        if(filtra) btnFiltra_Click(null, null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    userName = Session["USER_" + sessionID] as string;
                    DateTime inicio = DateTime.MinValue, fim = DateTime.MaxValue;
                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txbInicio.Text, txbInicio_CalendarExtender.Format, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out inicio))
                        txbInicio_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txbFim.Text, txbFim_CalendarExtender.Format, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fim))
                        txbFim_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
                    if (Session["TAREFAS_INV_"+sessionID] != null)
                        tarefas = (Dictionary<int, InvTarefas>)Session["TAREFAS_INV_"+sessionID];

                    if (Session["PARCELAS_"+sessionID] != null)
                    {
                        parcelas = (Dictionary<int, InvParcelaTarefa>)Session["PARCELAS_"+sessionID];
                        gvParcelas.DataSource = parcelas.Values.ToList();
                    }

                    if (Session["DOCUMENTOS_"+sessionID] != null)
                    {
                        documentos = (Dictionary<int, InvDocumento>)Session["DOCUMENTOS_"+sessionID];
                        gvDocumentos.DataSource = documentos.Values.ToList();
                    }

                }
            }

protected void btnFiltra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tarefas.Clear();
            List<string> idCliente, idPedido, idProjeto;
            DateTime inicio, fim;
            idCliente = cblCliente.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
            idPedido = cblPedido.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
            idProjeto = cblProjeto.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
            inicio = DateTime.MinValue;
            fim = DateTime.MaxValue;
            List<InvTarefas> tars = InvTarefas.getInvTarefas(new List<string>{"all"}, idCliente, idPedido, idProjeto, inicio, fim);
            if (tars != null && tars.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (InvTarefas tar in tars)
                {
                    tarefas.Add(tar.ID, tar);
                }
                this.Session["TAREFAS_INV_"+sessionID] = tarefas;
                gvTarefas.DataSource = tarefas.Values.ToList();
                gvTarefas.DataBind();
                pgvTarefasEmpty.Visible = false;
                gvTarefas.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Session["TAREFAS_INV_"+sessionID] = null;

                pgvTarefasEmpty.Visible = true;
                gvTarefas.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

After some help from a colleague, we found that the gvTarefas_OnRowCreated event was firing before the Page_load and that the code inside was trowing null exception.

I was also advised to change my event to OnRowDataBound.
 Also, for those of you who didn't knew you can set (when in trouble, otherwise is to much load) VS to stop on the line that throwed the exception by going Debug->Exceptions->Throw in Common Language Runtime Exceptions. If i knew this I probably had solved it right away.

Now, about the strange OnRowCreated before Page_Load, i still can't understand, but something tells me it's because of my UpdatePanel upBody that catches most of the page and its update mode is in Always (is the default value).

Last, i'm putting my OnRowCreated code

```
protected void gvTarefas_OnRowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            InvTarefas tar = e.Row.DataItem as InvTarefas;
            if (tar.EntidadeResponsavel != InvEntidadeResponsavel.PV_PROPRIO)
            {
                e.Row.Enabled = false;
                e.Row.CssClass = "PVPortlet_DisabledRoW";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Found an explanation for the OnCreateRow firing before Page_Load  http://forums.asp.net/t/1159230.aspx?GridView+RowCreated+event+before+Page_Load+